# owl-carousel: number product

Tags: slider

I installed **owl-carousel** into my Magento.
In home page there is only 5 items. I want to display 5 products.
How I make it?

My code:

```
{{block type="filterproducts/featured_home_list" column_count="5" product_count="10" category_id="7" product_count="12" template="filterproducts/list.phtml"}}

<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#featured_product .filter-products .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
            lazyLoad: true,
            itemsCustom: [[0, 1], [320, 1], [480, 2], [768, 3], [992, 2], [1280, 4]],
            responsiveRefreshRate: 50,
            slideSpeed: 200,
            paginationSpeed: 500,
            scrollPerPage: false,
            stopOnHover: true,
            rewindNav: true,
            rewindSpeed: 600,
            pagination: false,
            navigation: true,
            autoPlay: true,
            navigationText: ["<i class='icon-left-open'></i>", "<i class='icon-right-open'></i>"]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What's an error in your code ? Also if possible post website link

Comment: my code is correct but it show 4 products, not 5.

Comment: have you applied solution ?

Answer (score 1):

First define js lib in `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
   "shim": {
      "owlcarousel": [
         'jquery'
       ]
   },
   "paths": {
      "owlcarousel": "Vendor_Module/js/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min"
   }

};
```

Then in place you want to call carousel, place js script below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
            require([
                'jquery',
                'owlcarousel'
            ], function(jqy, owl){
                jqy('#featured_product .filter-products .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
                    // Your code
                });
            });
   //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: but my code work. i want like only show 5 products, not 4.

Answer (score 1):

add the item amount to your code for example after lazyload:true,

```
items: 5,
```

also check this line:

```
itemsCustom: [[0, 1], [320, 1], [480, 2], [768, 3], [992, 2], [1280, 4]]
```

for example when the width is 1280px -> show 4 items, if width is 992px -> show 2 items .....

Comment: sorry just tried to delete my comment.

Answer (score 1):

According to [OwlCarousel documentation](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-options.html), you should change `itemsCustom` option values.

```
itemsCustom : [ [SCREEN_WIDTH, NO_OF_ITEMS] ]
```

Here, you should change `NO_OF_ITEMS` according to `SCREEN_WIDTH`.

As per you code, I can suggest you to change it like:

```
itemsCustom: [[0, 1], [320, 1], [480, 2], [768, 3], [992, 2], [1280, 5]]
```

Note here, I have changed `NO_OF_ITEMS` for Screen size **greater than equals** to **1280**. Now you should able to see 5 items for screen size greater or equals to 1280.